# Wrap the code in shortcode to show on frontend page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin which input part number and return the price of the part. Every thing is working fine in WordPress dashboard. Now I want to wrap this in shortcode to show on frontend. Can anyone help me to do so.

Here is my Code

```
   function init() {
        test_pricelist_updated();
        $uploaded = test_csv_upload();
        if(!$uploaded) {
            $uploaded = test_form_submit();
       }
       if(!$uploaded) {
?>
    <h1>OE Part Number Checker</h1>
    <h2>Enter Part Numbers <small>(One per line)</small></h2>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea name="partnumbers" placeholder="XX0000..." rows="6" style="width: 300px"></textarea>
        <?php submit_button('Check Part Numbers') ?>
    </form>
    <hr/>
    <h2>Upload a CSV File</h2>
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='file' id='oe_csv' name='oe_csv' accept=".csv" required></input>
        <?php submit_button('Upload') ?>
    </form>
    <hr/>
    <h2>Update Price List CSV File</h2>
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='file' id='pricelist_csv' name='pricelist_csv' accept=".csv" required></input>
        <?php submit_button('Upload Pricelist CSV') ?>
    </form>
<?php
        }
    }
// I have tried this code to convert my code in a short code 

function init() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering

    test_pricelist_updated();
    $uploaded = test_csv_upload();
     if(!$uploaded) {
        ?>
        <h1>OE Part Number Checker</h1>
        <h2>Enter Part Numbers <small>(One per line)</small></h2>
        <form method="post">
            <textarea name="partnumbers" placeholder="XX0000..." rows="6" style="width: 300px"></textarea>
            <?php submit_button('Check Part Numbers') ?>
        </form>
        <hr/>
        <h2>Upload a CSV File</h2>
        <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type='file' id='oe_csv' name='oe_csv' accept=".csv" required></input>
            <?php submit_button('Upload') ?>
       </form>
       <hr/>
        <h2>Update Price List CSV File</h2>
        <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='file' id='pricelist_csv' name='pricelist_csv' accept=".csv" required></input>
        <?php submit_button('Upload Pricelist CSV') ?>
        </form>
       <?php
    }

    $content = ob_get_clean(); // Capture the content and clear the buffer
    return $content;
}

function fts_africa_oecheck_shortcode() {
    return init();
}

add_shortcode('fts_africa_oecheck', 'fts_africa_oecheck_shortcode');
```

I have tried this by add_shortcode hook but its showing only input box but not showing any csv upload button and submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation  for [submit_button](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/submit_button/) has notes about restrictions outside *admin*.

A similar function does not seems to have same restrictions [get_submit_button](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_submit_button/) and may solve your case. Eg:

```
 <?php echo get_submit_button('Check Part Numbers');?>
```

**Update** because the get_submit_button function is not included outside admin states too.

In order to provide an answer, maybe you can define the function by yourself based on the original source in the documentation. Seems to serialize the submit button given some parameters:

```php
if(!function_exists("get_submit_button")) {

    function get_submit_button( $text = '', $type = 'primary large', $name = 'submit', $wrap = true, $other_attributes = '' ) {
        if ( ! is_array( $type ) ) {
            $type = explode( ' ', $type );
        }

        $button_shorthand = array( 'primary', 'small', 'large' );
        $classes          = array( 'button' );

        foreach ( $type as $t ) {
            if ( 'secondary' === $t || 'button-secondary' === $t ) {
                continue;
            }

            $classes[] = in_array( $t, $button_shorthand, true ) ? 'button-' . $t : $t;
        }

        $class = implode( ' ', array_unique( array_filter( $classes ) ) );

        $text = $text ? $text : __( 'Save Changes' );

        $id = $name;
        if ( is_array( $other_attributes ) && isset( $other_attributes['id'] ) ) {
            $id = $other_attributes['id'];
            unset( $other_attributes['id'] );
        }

        $attributes = '';
        if ( is_array( $other_attributes ) ) {
            foreach ( $other_attributes as $attribute => $value ) {
                $attributes .= $attribute . '="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" '; // Trailing space is important.
            }
        } elseif ( ! empty( $other_attributes ) ) { // Attributes provided as a string.
            $attributes = $other_attributes;
        }

        $name_attr = $name ? ' name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '"' : '';
        $id_attr   = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $button  = '<input type="submit"' . $name_attr . $id_attr . ' class="' . esc_attr( $class );
        $button .= '" value="' . esc_attr( $text ) . '" ' . $attributes . ' />';

        if ( $wrap ) {
            $button = '<p class="submit">' . $button . '</p>';
        }

        return $button;
    }

}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_submit_button() This error showing when i try to add get_submit_button

Comment: Yes my bad, it's not available too. Because of its contents you can try to define it yourself.